# JsonCpp symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, json

I am new to C++ and was using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) to parse C++ object to Json and vice-versa. However, the following code keep giving me the error as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)", referenced from:
      Account::toJson() in Account.o
  "Json::Value::Value(int)", referenced from:
      Account::toJson() in Account.o
  "Json::Value::~Value()", referenced from:
      Account::toJson() in Account.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here is the code Account.cpp:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "json/json.h"
#include "Account.h"

Account::Account() {
    id_ = 0;
    balance_ = 0;
    income_ = 0;
}

Account::Account(int id, int balance, int income, std::string date) {

    id_ = id;
    balance_ = balance;
    income_ = income;
    date_ = date;
}

Account::~Account() {

}

// Getters and setters omitted

Json::Value Account::toJson() {
    Json::Value value(Json::objectValue);
    value["id"] = id_;
    value["balance"] = balance_;
    value["income"] = income_;
    value["date"] = date_;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?